# how to fetch data inside bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-popover

Im ussing angular 9 and bootstrap 4.3.1

I'm trying to use popover to show a list of option which the user can choose from by clicking on the item he selcted, everithing work fine the only problem is when I use the

```
(click)="someFunction"
```

on any element inside the popover contet data
**it does not** trigger the function in the .js component

this is part of the html

```
<div id="fromFloor-content" style="visibility: hidden">
<div id='popoverForSale' class='container  rtl  pr-3'>
  <input name="test" ngModel type="checkbox"  >
  <div class='row' id='popoverFromFloor'>
    <button id='eee' class='col p-2 btn btn-link' style='text-decoration: none' (click)="test('all')">all</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row' id='popoverFromFloor'>
    <button class='col p-2 btn btn-link' style='text-decoration: none' (click)="test('0')>0</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row' id='popoverFromFloor'>
    <button class='col p-2 btn btn-link' style='text-decoration: none' (click)="test('1')>1</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row' id='popoverFromFloor'>
    <button class='col p-2 btn btn-link' style='text-decoration: none' (click)="test('2')>2</button>
  </div>
```

js file

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

$('#fromFloor[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  html: true,
  sanitize: false,
  trigger: 'focus',
  container: 'body',
  content: function() {
    return $('#fromFloor-content').html();
  },
});
  }

  test(buttonContent:string) {
console.log(buttonContent);
```

}

how can I trigger the buttons inside the popover?`

Comment: check this: https://therichpost.com/angular-9-popover-login-form-working-code/

Comment: thanks but it desnt help, I can reach the field in code by using the form but it dosent help me fixing the problom that the (click) event dosent work inside the popover content

Comment: but validation works.